# Refinement of a famous inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math

I refine a famous inequality this is the following  :

> Let $x,y>0$ then we have :
> $$x^n+y^n\leq \Big(\frac{x^n+y^n}{x^{n-1}+y^{n-1}} \Big)^n+\Big(\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)^n$$
> It's equivalent to :
> $$x^n+1\leq \Big(\frac{x^n+1}{x^{n-1}+1} \Big)^n+\Big(\frac{x+1}{2}\Big)^n$$
> Because it's homogeneous .
> We can't use AM GM  it's too weak so the difficulty  is interesting .
> I try to derivate this but it's a little bit ugly .
> I have two questions how interpreting this result and how to solve this one variable inequality  ?

Thanks a lot

**Remark** (@Andreas, 2020-10-25)

1. This inequality is rather fine-tuned. Consider as a first term on the RHS  $$\Big(\frac{x^n+y^n+z\cdot(\frac{x+y}{2})^n}{x^{n-1}+y^{n-1}+z\cdot(\frac{x+y}{2})^{n-1}}\Big)^n
   $$
   and let $z$ increase from $0$ to $1$. It is easy to see that the increase of $z$ makes the term smaller. Choosing $z=0$ (this question) makes the term "just big enough" for the inequality to be "$\le$". Indeed, for $z=1$, this inverses to "$\ge$", as [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347245/) shows. So, fine tuned upper and lower bounds to $x^n + y^n$ are available.
2. An interesting observation is the following:
   $$\Big(\frac{x^n+y^n}{x^{n-1}+y^{n-1}} \Big)^n \ge x^n+y^n - \Big(\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)^n \ge \frac{x^n+y^n}{2} .$$
   The first inequality is the one under consideration, the second one is an application of Jensen's inequality for two values of the function $x^n$, whereas the inequality between the first and the third expression is a direct application of Slater's inequality* [(eq. (2) in  this pdf)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002190458190112X/pdf?md5=ccc512dda8a0e27eb9344f1b052fe563&pid=1-s2.0-002190458190112X-main.pdf), so we see here a *sharpening of Slater's inequality* for the function  $x^n$.

*Slater ML, A Companion Inequality to Jensen's Inequality. Jour. of Approximation Theory 1981, 32(2):160–166.

Comment: what are you exactly asking? You want us to prove the inequality you wrote or do you want to find out if it is true?

Comment: I think I got a rather cumbersome solution and will type it up sometime tomorrow.

Comment: One of the tags is [tag:contest-math]. Is this from an ongoing contest?

Comment: Now there is a solution.

Comment: @FatsWallers Where you took this problem?

Comment: @FatsWallers Your question was taken by Michael Rozenberg to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337457 and found quite some interest (and two answers) there. Thus it would be nice if you tell a little more about your question. What is the "famous inequality" you are referring to? Did you conjecture the posted inequality, and if not, where did you find it?

Comment: Maybe this could explain the motivation: if you look at this question of FatsWallers https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260994/new-bounds-for-convex-function-of-2-variables  the right hand side is exactly the inequality asked here for $f(x)=x^{n}$. The author claims "it follows from karamata" -  this is not true, for example, $f(x)=x^{3}+x^{2}+100 x$ gives counterexample on $[0,1]$. Nevertheless, apparently by some reasons the inequality still holds for $f(x)=x^{n}, n\geq 1$ and, in a sense, it does refine Karamata's inequality even though  vectors do not majorize each other.

Comment: @PaataIvanishvili Yes, that's very plausible. And right, the answer to the other question is no, even for the simpler example $x^3+ax$ for every positive $a$.