# Inequality : $\Big(\frac{x^n+1+(\frac{x+1}{2})^n}{x^{n-1}+1+(\frac{x+1}{2})^{n-1}}\Big)^n+\Big(\frac{x+1}{2}\Big)^n\leq x^n+1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, jensen-inequality

I have the following problem to solve :

> Let $x,y>0$ and $n>1$ a natural number then we have :
> $$\Big(\frac{x^n+y^n+(\frac{x+y}{2})^n}{x^{n-1}+y^{n-1}+(\frac{x+y}{2})^{n-1}}\Big)^n+\Big(\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)^n\leq x^n+y^n$$

The problem is equivalent to :
$$\Big(\frac{x^n+1+(\frac{x+1}{2})^n}{x^{n-1}+1+(\frac{x+1}{2})^{n-1}}\Big)^n+\Big(\frac{x+1}{2}\Big)^n\leq x^n+1$$
Or ($y^2=x$):
$$\Big(\frac{y^{2n}+1+(\frac{y^2+1}{2})^n}{y^{2(n-1)}+1+(\frac{y^2+1}{2})^{n-1}}\Big)^n+\Big(\frac{y^2+1}{2}\Big)^n\leq y^{2n}+1$$
I try the following identity :
$$ch^2(x)-sh^2(x)=1$$

So we put $y=sh(x)$ we get :
$$\Big(\frac{sh^{2n}(x)+1+(\frac{ch^2(x)}{2})^n}{sh^{2(n-1)}(x)+1+(\frac{ch^2(x)}{2})^{n-1}}\Big)^n+\Big(\frac{ch^2(x)}{2}\Big)^n\leq sh^{2n}(x)+1$$

And after I'm stuck...

### Update case $n=3$ :

Due to homogeneity we can assume :
$$x^{2}+y^{2}+\Big(\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)^{2}=1$$

Remains to show :

$$\Big(x^3+y^3+\Big(\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)^3\Big)^3+\Big(\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)^{3}-x^3-y^3\leq 0$$

Or :

$$\frac{1}{512} (x + y) (729 x^8 + 972 x^6 y^2 + 1728 x^5 y^3 + 54 x^4 y^4 + 1728 x^3 y^5 + 972 x^2 y^6 - 448 x^2 + 640 x y + 729 y^8 - 448 y^2)\quad(1)$$

Or :

$$\frac{1}{512} (x + y)(27 (x + y)^2 (3 x^2 - 2 x y + 3 y^2)^3-448y^2-448z^2+640xy)$$

Or :

$$\frac{1}{512} (x + y)(27 (x + y)^2 (3 x^2 - 2 x y + 3 y^2)^3-64 (7 x^2 - 10 x y + 7 y^2))$$

But with the constraint :

$$\frac{5x^2}{4}+\frac{xy}{2}+\frac{5y^2}{4}=1$$

Or :

$$x^2+y^2=\Big(1-\frac{xy}{2}\Big)\frac{4}{5}$$

It gives :

$$\frac{1}{512} (x + y)\Big(27 (x + y)^2 \Big(\Big(1-\frac{xy}{2}\Big)\frac{12}{5}-2xy\Big)^3-64 \Big(\Big(1-\frac{xy}{2}\Big)\frac{28}{5}-10xy\Big)\Big )$$

Or :

$$\frac{1}{512} (x + y)\Big(27 \Big(\Big(1-\frac{xy}{2}\Big)\Big)\frac{4}{5}+2xy) \Big(\Big(1-\frac{xy}{2}\Big)\frac{12}{5}-2xy\Big)^3-64 \Big(\Big(1-\frac{xy}{2}\Big)\frac{28}{5}-10xy\Big)\Big)$$

We put the substitution $a=xy$ .There is a root at $a=\frac{1}{3}$ it gives :

$$\frac{1}{512} (x + y)\Big(-\frac{512}{625} (3 a - 1) (576 a^3 - 816 a^2 + 52 a - 73)\Big)$$

Now with the constraint it's not hard to see that $a\leq \frac{1}{3}$

And $$f(a)=(576 a^3 - 816 a^2 + 52 a - 73)\leq 0$$ on $[0,\frac{1}{3}]$

So the quantity $(1)$ is negative . We are done for this case .

If you have a hint it would be cool .

Thanks a lot !

Comment: "The problem is equivalent to [...]" -- I don't see how. Just because it holds for $y=1$ doesn't mean it holds for other $y>0$.

Comment: In fact it's homogeneity wich does that .

Comment: Interestingly, the condition "$n$ a natural number" is necessary. If this were not required, here is a counterexample: Let $x=0.01$, $y=1$, $n=1.1$, then we can do the calculations and obtain for the LHS and RHS: 1.0170 < 1.0063 which is obvioulsy wrong. It appears that for $n \ge 2$ no such counterexamples can be found.

Comment: @Andreas The least value for $n$ for which the inequality is true for $x, y > 0$ is approximately $1.725$ (the exact value is the solution to $2^{n}-\left(2-\frac{2}{2^{n}+2}\right)^{n}=1$). If $n$ is larger than that, then it doesn't matter whether $n$ is in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Andreas Ok, I'll complete that part... I do feel a bit irresponsible leaving a simple "by induction" lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's begin with your 2nd inequality with $x$ only.

Let $x = (1+p)/(1-p)$ and we have $x>0\iff p\in(-1,1)$, then your inequality becomes

$$\left(\frac{(1+p)^n+(1-p)^n+1}{(1+p)^{n-1}+(1-p)^{n-1}+1}\right)^n+1\le\!\!\!?\;(1+p)^n+(1-p)^n.$$

Let $a_n = (1+p)^n+(1-p)^n$, by symmetry we can assume $p\in(0,1)$ (the case $p=0$ is trivial), then we have

$$\left(\frac{a_n+1}{a_{n-1}+1}\right)^n+1\le\!\!\!?\;a_n.$$

Note that $\left(\frac{a_n+1}{a_{n-1}+1}\right)$ is increasing [1], we have

$$\left(\frac{a_n+1}{a_{n-1}+1}\right)^n\le\left(\frac{a_n+1}{a_{n-1}+1}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{a_{n+1}+1}{a_{n}+1}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{a_{2n-1}+1}{a_{2n-2}+1}\right)=\left(\frac{a_{2n-1}+1}{a_{n-1}+1}\right).$$

Thus, your inequality can be proved if we have

$$\frac{a_{2n-1}+1}{a_{n-1}+1}\le\!\!\!?\;a_n-1,$$

Note that $(a_n-1)(a_{n-1}+1)=a_{2n-1}+2(1-p^2)^{n-1}+a_n-a_{n-1}-1$, so the inequality above becomes

$$(1-p^2)^{n}+\frac12(a_{n+1}-a_n)\ge\!\!\!?\;1.$$

Let $(u_n)$ be the LHS, we have $u_0=u_1=1$, and we can prove that $(u_n)$ is increasing [2], which finishes the proof.

PS. In fact, a stronger inequality has been proved. The following equalities can be useful:
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+pb_n,\quad b_{n+1}=b_n+pa_n,$$
with $b_n=(1+p)^n-(1-p)^n$.

---

Update.

[1]
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}+1}{a_n+1}\ge\frac{a_{n}+1}{a_{n-1}+1} & \iff(a_{n+1}+1)(a_{n-1}+1)\ge(a_n+1)^2\\
&\impliedby a_{2n}+a_2(1-p^2)^{n-1}+1\ge a_{2n}+2(1-p^2)^n+1\tag{*}\\
&\iff (1+p)^2+(1-p)^2 \ge 2(1+p)(1-p)\\
&\iff (2p)^2\ge0.
\end{align}

(*): we have $a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}\ge2a_n$ since

$$a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}\ge2a_n\iff b_{n}\ge b_{n-1}\iff a_{n-1}\ge 0.$$

[2]
\begin{align}
u_{n+1}\ge u_{n} & \iff \frac p2 b_{n+1}+(1-p^2)^{n+1}\ge\frac p2 b_{n}+(1-p^2)^{n}\\
& \iff\frac {p^2}2a_{n}\ge p^2(1-p^2)^{n}\\
& \iff \frac1{(1-p)^n}+\frac1{(1+p)^n}\ge2.\\
\end{align}

As mentioned by @Andreas, the last inequality is true since
$$\frac1{(1-p)^n}+\frac1{(1+p)^n}\ge \frac2{(1-p^2)^{n/2}}\ge2.$$

Comment: A few inductions which "can be proved" - please do.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah I know... The calculation is quite a disaster, that's why I don't even want to touch them. But a priori proving two sequences are increasing is not an impossible task and there should be many ways to do that. I wrote "by induction" just because I'm lazy...

Comment: @Andreas Done :)

Comment: There are terms missing in the second new line (the induction works nevertheless once a few more steps are proven):
\begin{align}
&\iff a_{2n}+a_2(1-p^2)^{n-1}+{\color{red}{a_{n+1} + a_{n-1}}} + 1\ge a_{2n}+2(1-p^2)^n+{\color{red}{2 a_{n} }}+1
\end{align}

Comment: The last step needed, $\frac1{(1-p)^n}+\frac1{(1+p)^n}\ge2$,  can be proven more or less directly with AM-GM-inequality, giving $\frac1{(1-p)^n}+\frac1{(1+p)^n}\ge \frac2{(1-p^2)^{n/2}}\ge2$ where the last step is evident.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for pointing out. I skipped a step when copying from my draft.

Comment: It's good that now all steps are visible - that makes the proof comprehensible for other readers, which is what this site is made for .....

Answer (score 4):

Consider the inequality in the form

$$\Big(\frac{x^n+y^n+(\frac{x+y}{2})^n}{x^{n-1}+y^{n-1}+(\frac{x+y}{2})^{n-1}}\Big)^n+\Big(\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)^n\leq x^n+y^n
$$
Due to homegeneity, let $\frac{x+y}{2} = 1$. Denote $\frac{x-y}{2} = a$. Then we consider the equivalent question, w.l.o.g. with $0\le a \le 1$:
$$
\Big(\frac{(1+a)^n+(1-a)^n+1}{(1+a)^{n-1} +(1-a)^{n-1}  + 1 }\Big)^n \leq- 1+ (1+a)^n+(1-a)^n
$$

Note that for every convex function $f(x)$ and $p_i \ge 0$ the following is true (Jensen):

$$
f\Big( \frac{p_1 x_1 + p_2 x_2 + p_3 x_3 }{p_1  + p_2  + p_3  }\Big) \le \frac{p_1 f(x_1) + p_2 f(x_2) + p_3 f(x_3) }{p_1  + p_2  + p_3  }
$$

Since $f(x) = x^n$ is a convex function, apply Jensen to the LHS with $p_1 = (1+a)^{n-1}$, $p_2 = (1-a)^{n-1}$, $p_3 = 1$, and $x_1 = 1+a$, $x_2 = 1-a$, $x_3 = 1$. Then it is sufficient to prove

$$
\frac{(1+a)^{n-1} (1+a)^{n} + (1-a)^{n-1} (1-a)^{n} + 1}{(1+a)^{n-1} +(1-a)^{n-1}  + 1 } \le - 1+ (1+a)^n+(1-a)^n
$$
Clearing denominators gives
$$
g(a,n) =  -(2 + (1+a)^n+(1-a)^n) + (1+a)^n(1+(1-a)^{n-1}) + (1-a)^n(1+(1+a)^{n-1})  \;\\
\; = 2 (1 - a^2)^{n-1} + a ((1+a)^{n-1} - (1-a)^{n-1} ) -2  \ge 0
$$
But $g(a,n)$ is, for every $n \ge 2$, a  function which is monotonously increasing in  $a$. Namely,
$g(a=0,n) = 0$ and $g(a=1,n) = 2^{n-1} -2$.

This can be proved by induction over $n$. We have that the assumption holds for $n=2$ since $g(a,n=2) = 0$ $\forall a$. Do the step $n \to n+1$. We need to show
$$
g(a, n+1) = 2 (1 - a^2)^{n} + a ((1+a)^{n} - (1-a)^{n} ) -2  \ge 0
$$
This can be rewritten
$$
g(a, n+1) = g(a, n) +  a^2 [(1+a)^{n-2} + (1-a)^{n-2}  - 2((1+a)(1-a))^{n-2}] \ge 0
$$

Since $g(a, n) \ge 0$ by induction hypothesis, this holds true if the second bracket is nonnegative. Use the AM-GM inequality  for the first two terms in this bracket, giving the stronger condition
$2 ((1+a)(1-a))^{(n-2)/2} - 2((1+a)(1-a))^{n-2} \ge 0
$ or $(1-a^2)^{(n-2)/2} \le 1
$ which is obviously true.

This proves the claim. $\qquad \Box$

**Remark:** This inequality is rather fine-tuned. Consider as a first factor   $$\Big(\frac{x^n+y^n+z\cdot(\frac{x+y}{2})^n}{x^{n-1}+y^{n-1}+z\cdot(\frac{x+y}{2})^{n-1}}\Big)^n
$$
and let $z$ increase from 0 to 1. It is easy to see that the increase of $z$ makes the term smaller. Choosing $z=1$ makes the term "just small enough" for the inequality to be "$\le$". Indeed, for $z=0$, this inverses to "$\ge$", as [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3304808/refinement-of-a-famous-inequality) (with [this proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337457/prove-that-left-fracxn1xn-11-rightn-left-fracx12-rightn)) shows.

Numerically, one can solve for the particular value $z^*$ where equality occurs. It shows that for all $n$, we have $\lim_{a \to 0} z^* = 0$. The highest value for  $z^*$ occurs for $n=2$ and $a=1$ with $z^* = \sqrt 3 - 1 \simeq 0.732$. For $n \ge3$ and all $a$, we have that $z^* < 0.423$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that your answer did almost the same thing as mine. I'd keep mine since somehow it's easier to read. (+1)

Comment: @Aforest Well, what is easier to read is arguable .... What's common to both proofs is the almost identical concept of introducing the excess (p in your text, a in mine) and the inductions. Where we differ is in the treatment of the first term where I used Jensen's inequality and you introduced telescoping - very nice idea!  Jensen saved me one induction proof where you needed two.