# About a Conjecture: $-\left(\frac{x^{n}+1}{x^{n-1}+1}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^{n}+\left(x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}+\sqrt{x}-1\right)^{n}+1\leq 0$

Tags: inequality, karamata-inequality

Hi it's a conjecture wich refine for $0< x\leq 1$ the inequality [Refinement of a famous inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3304808/refinement-of-a-famous-inequality) :

### Problem/Conjecture

Let $0<x\leq 1$ then for $n\geq 3$ a natural number it seems we have the inequality :

$$f(x)=-\left(\frac{x^{n}+1}{x^{n-1}+1}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^{n}+\left(x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}+\sqrt{x}-1\right)^{n}+1\leq 0$$

Some material :

Here [New bound for Am-Gm of 2 variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253006/new-bound-for-am-gm-of-2-variables) I have proved using Gerber's theorem , the inequality :

$$\left(x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}+\sqrt{x}-1\right)^{n}\geq x^n$$

And here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337457/prove-that-left-fracxn1xn-11-rightn-left-fracx12-rightn the inequality in the first link is shown greatly .

Idea for a proof (weaker in fact):

It seems we have under the constraint above  :

$$\left(\frac{x^{n}+1}{x^{n-1}+1}\right)-\left(\frac{\left(n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\geq 0$$

And :

$$\left(\frac{x^{n}+1}{x^{n-1}+1}\right)-\frac{\left(x+1\right)}{2}\geq 0$$

And for $x\in(0,0.5]$:

$$x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}+\sqrt{x}-1-\left(\frac{\left(n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\le 0$$

And finally for $x\in(0,0.5]$ :

$$\left(\frac{x^{n}+1}{x^{n-1}+1}\right)+\frac{\left(x+1\right)}{2}-\left(x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}+\sqrt{x}-1\right)-\left(\frac{\left(n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\ge0$$

So applying the Karamata's inequality on $f(x)=x^n$ with  $x\in[0,0.5]$ gives a weaker result if i'm not wrong .

Edit :

Using the bounds above  we have a bound for the derivative for $n\geq 6$ :

$$j\left(x\right)=-n\left(\frac{x^{2n}+1}{x^{2\left(n-1\right)}+1}\right)^{\left(n-1\right)}\cdot\frac{2x^{2n+1}\left(x^{2n}+n\left(x^{2}-1\right)+1\right)}{\left(x^{2n}+x^{2}\right)^{2}}-2^{-n}\cdot2n\cdot x\left(x^{2}+1\right)^{\left(n-1\right)}+n\left(x^{2}\right)^{\left(n-1\right)}\cdot\left(\left(2x^{2}\right)x\cdot\frac{\left(x^{2}+2\ln\left(x\right)+1\right)}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)^{2}}+1\right)\leq \frac{d}{dx}f\left(x^{2}\right)$$

How to (dis)prove it ?

Comment: We can (if true) choose $$\left(\frac{x^{n}+1}{x^{n-1}+1}\right)-\left(\frac{\left(n-1\right)}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\ge 0$$ for $n\geq 10$ and $x\in(0,0.5]$ it works as well .

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer just a useful remark :

We can split the problem because it seems we have :

Let $\exists x\in(0,1]$ and $\exists n\geq 3$ a natural number such that

$$\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{n}}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}-nx\right)\left(x^{n}+1\right)^{n}}{\left(x^{\left(n-1\right)}+1\right)^{n}}+nx-\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{2^{n}}-1\geq 0$$

And :

$$\frac{\left(x+1\right)^{n}}{2^{n}}+\frac{\left(nx-\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)\left(x^{n}+1\right)^{n}}{\left(x^{\left(n-1\right)}+1\right)^{n}}-nx+\frac{1}{2^{n}}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\left(x^{\frac{x}
{x+1}}+\sqrt{x}-1\right)^{n}\ge0$$

I go a little bit further :

Define :

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(nx-\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)\left(x^{n}+1\right)^{n}}{\left(x^{\left(n-1\right)}+1\right)^{n}}-\left(n-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)x+1/n^{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n}},g(x)=\frac{\left(x+1\right)^{n}}{2^{n}}-\frac{1+2x}{2^{n}},h\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{2^{n}}-\left(\sqrt{x}+x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}-1\right)^{n}$$

Let $a,b\in(0,1)$ $\exists x\in(a,b]$ and $\exists n\geq 3$ a natural number such that :

$$h(x)>0,f(x)>0,g(x)>0$$

---

---

We can also study the inequality for $x,y,z\in[0.5,1]$ and $n\geq 10$:

$$0\le y^{n}+z^{n}-1-\left(x-1\right)^{n}$$

This inequality seems true for :

Let :

$r(x)=\frac{x^{n}+1}{x^{n-1}+1}$

Denotes by $d=x_{min}\in[0.5,1]$ the value such that :

$$r'(d)=0$$

Then taking $z\in[d-1/2^{n},1]$ and $x\in[0.5,1]$ and $y=r(x)$ the inequality generalized seems true .

I haven't a proof yet but with all this stuff we can show the inequality .

---

Comment: We can also introduce the function : $f\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(x+1\right)^{n}}{2^{n}}+\frac{\left(x^{n}+1\right)^{n}}{\left(x^{\left(n-1\right)}+1\right)^{n}}-1-\left(x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}+\sqrt{x}-1\right)^{n}$ and : $j(x)=f(x)-f(1-x)$ seems convex for $0.5\leq x\leq 0.8$ and $n\geq 30$

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer - Just a few elements*

$$f(x)=-\left(\frac{x^{n}+1}{x^{n-1}+1}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^{n}+\left(x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}+\sqrt{x}-1\right)^{n}+1$$ gives $f(0)=-2^{-n}$ and $f(1)=0$. We also have $f'(0)=-n\, 2^{-n} <0 $ and $f'(1)=0^-$

When $n$ is large, we have
$$f(x)=-\frac{n \left(n^3-n-1\right) }{192 }(1-x)^4+O\left((x-1)^5\right)$$ which is always negative.

So, $f(x)$ starts decreasing and goes through a minimum value. We can *approximate* where the minimum occurs using the series expansion of $f'(x)$ and series reversion to get
$$x_*=1-\frac{8 \left(n^3-n-1\right)}{5 \left(n^4-4 n^3-n^2+2 n+5\right)}-$$ $$\frac{64 \left(n^3-n-1\right)^2 \left(n^5-60 n^4+160 n^3+30 n^2+19
   n-246\right)}{625 \left(n^4-4 n^3-n^2+2 n+5\right)^3}+\cdots$$

The problem is that we need a lot of terms before arriving at
$$x_* \sim 1-\frac{4}{n}+\frac{7}{2n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ which does not seem to be too bad
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution}\\
 3 & 0.055556 &  0.079320 \\
 4 & 0.218750 &  0.228742 \\
 5 & 0.340000 &  0.346682 \\
 6 & 0.430556 &  0.435779 \\
 7 & 0.500000 &  0.504355 \\
 8 & 0.554688 &  0.558444 \\
 9 & 0.598765 &  0.602076 \\
 10 & 0.635000 &  0.637962 \\
 20 & 0.808750 &  0.810192 \\
 30 & 0.870556 &  0.871505 \\
 40 & 0.902188 &  0.902894 \\
 50 & 0.921400 &  0.921962 \\
 60 & 0.934306 &  0.934773 \\
 70 & 0.943571 &  0.943971 \\
 80 & 0.950547 &  0.950895 \\
  90 & 0.955988 &  0.956297 \\
 100 & 0.960350 &  0.960628 \\
 200 & 0.980088 &  0.980226 \\
 300 & 0.986706 &  0.986797 \\
 400 & 0.990022 &  0.990091 \\
 500 & 0.992014 &  0.992069 \\
 600 & 0.993343 &  0.993389 \\
 700 & 0.994293 &  0.994332 \\
 800 & 0.995005 &  0.995040 \\
 900 & 0.995560 &  0.995590 \\
1000 & 0.996004 &  0.996031 \\
2000 & 0.998001 &  0.998015 \\
 3000 & 0.998667 &  0.998676 \\
 4000 & 0.999000 &  0.999007 \\
 5000 & 0.999200 &  0.999206 \\
 6000 & 0.999333 &  0.999338 \\
 7000 & 0.999429 &  0.999433 \\
 8000 & 0.999500 &  0.999503 \\
  9000 & 0.999556 &  0.999559 \\
 10000 & 0.999600 &  0.999603
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

We also have
$$f''(0)=-n(n-1)\,2^{-n} \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(1)=0^-$$ As soon as $n>3$, there are two inflection points.