# Proof about concave decreasing function with some constraints

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, alternative-proof

Hi it's a follow up of [How to prove that the functional equation $f(x)+f(y)=f(\frac{xf'(x)+yf'(y)}{f'(x)+f'(y)})+f(\frac{x+y}2)$ is verified only by some basic functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3335601/how-to-prove-that-the-functional-equation-fxfy-f-fracxfxyfyfx) :

Conjecture :

Let $a,x>0$ and $f(x)$ be continuous,  and twice differentiable on $I=(a,b)$ such that $f(x)$ is concave increasing and $f(0)=0$, $x\geq\frac{x+a}{2}\geq \frac{xf'\left(x\right)+af'\left(a\right)}{f'\left(x\right)+f'\left(a\right)}\geq a\geq  \varepsilon\geq 0$  and $f'\left(x\right)+f'\left(a\right)\neq 0$ and $\frac{xf'\left(x\right)+af'\left(a\right)}{f'\left(x\right)+f'\left(a\right)}-\frac{x+a}{2}+\epsilon=0$ then it seems we have :

$$g\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)+f\left(a\right)-f\left(\frac{x+a}{2}\right)-f\left(\frac{\left(xf'\left(x\right)+af'\left(a\right)\right)}{f'\left(x\right)+f'\left(a\right)}\right)-f(\epsilon)\le 0$$

---

---

Proof :

As we assume :

$$a\le x$$

So we have :

$$\frac{a+x}{2}-a\leq 0$$

And :

$$\frac{a+x}{2}+\frac{\left(af'\left(a\right)+xf'\left(x\right)\right)}{f'\left(a\right)+f'\left(x\right)}-a-x\le 0$$

From the constraint  .And the last step follows again from one of the constraint

So applying Karamata's inequality to the function $j(x)=-f(x)$ gives the result .

Is it correct ?
Have you an alternative proof ?

Comment: What does it mean to say $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)\neq constant$

Comment: We an also use strong convexity with $f\left(\frac{\left(x+a\right)}{2}-\frac{\left(xf'\left(x\right)+af'\left(a\right)\right)}{f'\left(x\right)+f'\left(a\right)}\right)+\frac{f''\left(a\right)}{2}\left(\left(\frac{\left(x+a\right)}{2}-\frac{\left(xf'\left(x\right)+af'\left(a\right)\right)}{f'\left(x\right)+f'\left(a\right)}\right)^{2}+\frac{\left(x-a\right)^{2}}{4}+\left(a-\frac{\left(xf'\left(x\right)+af'\left(a\right)\right)}{f'\left(x\right)+f'\left(a\right)}\right)^{2}\right)$ where I use this https://journalofinequalitiesandapplications.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13660-019-2007-9