# Counter-example wanted on a new formula for convex function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, examples-counterexamples, jensen-inequality

I'm confusing because in the inequality [New bounds for convex function of 2 variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3260994/new-bounds-for-convex-function-of-2-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1) the RHS doesn't work (take $f(x)=\tan(x)$) so I propose a new formula that I have checked for all the elementary convex functions . I recognize that I'm inspired like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3289914/very-sharp-inequality-in-the-style-of-c-p-niculescu?noredirect=1&lq=1) by the upper estimate of Jensen's inequality found by C.p Niculescu .To recall we have also the Slater's inequality wich is the compagnion of the Jensen's inequality . I used it to give a new estimate like this .

> Let $f(x)$ be a twice differentiable function on an interval $I$ such that :
>
> $1)$ $f'(x)>0$  $\forall x \in I $
>
> $2)$ $f''(x)>0$  $\forall x \in I $
>
> Then for $a,b,c,d\in I$ such that $a\geq b\geq c\geq d $ we have :
> $$|f(a)+f(d)-f\Big(\frac{af'(a)+df'(d)}{f'(a)+f'(d)}\Big)-f\Big(\frac{a+d}{2}\Big)|\geq |f(b)+f(c)-f\Big(\frac{bf'(b)+cf'(c)}{f'(b)+f'(c)}\Big)-f\Big(\frac{b+c}{2}\Big)|$$

Furthermore I add absolute value because the inequality can be reversed as we know .

My question is : Have you a counter-example ?

Many thanks .

Comment: In your another post, you use Karamata's inequality to obtain that here the stuff in the absolute sign is non-positive, right?

Answer (score 1):

Given $f$, I used Mathcad to draw a (two-dimensional) graph of a function $$h(x,y)=\left|f(x)+f(y)-f\Big(\frac{xf'(x)+yf'(y)}{f'(x)+f'(y)}\Big)-f\Big(\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)\right|$$ and then looked for “monotonicity violation” of $h$. The second try was $f(x)=x^3$ and I quickly found that $$h(0.2,10)\simeq 131.468>129.168\simeq h(0.01,10.1).$$