# An olympiad-like inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math, functional-inequalities, jensen-inequality

I found this problem in my old paper :

> Let $f(x)$ be a convex function on $(0,\infty)$ such that $\forall x>0$ we have $f(x)>0$ and $n\geq 3$ a natural number then we have :
>   $$\Big(f(1)^{f(1)}f(2)^{f(2)}\cdots f(n)^{f(n)}\Big)^{\frac{1}{f(1)+f(2)+\cdots + f(n)}}+\Big(f(1)f(2)\cdots f(n)\Big)^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq f(1)+f(n) $$

I try to use Jensen's inequality we have :

$$\ln\Big( \Big(f(1)^{f(1)}f(2)^{f(2)}\cdots f(n)^{f(n)}\Big)^{\frac{1}{f(1)+f(2)+\cdots + f(n)}} \Big)\leq \ln\Big(\frac{f^2(1)+f^2(2)+\cdots+f^2(n)}{f(1)+f(2)+\cdots+f(n)}\Big)$$

Remains to show this :

$$\ln\Big(\frac{f^2(1)+f^2(2)+\cdots+f^2(n)}{f(1)+f(2)+\cdots+f(n)}\Big)\leq \ln\Big(f(1)+f(n)-\Big(f(1)f(2)\cdots f(n)\Big)^{\frac{1}{n}}\Big)$$

This last inequality is true for $f(x)=e^x$ but certainly not for $f(x)=x$

Furthermore this result recall me the Mercer's inequality (see [here](https://bib.irb.hr/datoteka/540923.Jensen-MercerKLP.pdf))

Finally If the function $f(x)$ is concave and positive the inequality of the beginning is reversed .

I think it's too hard for an maths competition but you can use the tools you want .

I prefer hints as answer.

Thanks a lot for sharing your time and knowledge .

Edit :

Ooops I don't mentionned that the case $n=2$ is special it correspond to this

[New bound for Am-Gm of 2 variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253006/new-bound-for-am-gm-of-2-variables)

Second edit :

I disturbed me a little bit but I think we can add the following constraint.
I add the fact that $\ln(f(x))$ must be concave on $(0,\infty)$.If it's doesn't work too can someone prove the inequality for $f(x)=x\alpha$ where $\alpha>0$ ?

Thanks again !

Comment: If I calculated correctly then your inequality is *wrong* for $f(x)=x$ and $n=2$. The LHS is $3.001614614341294 > f(1) + f(2) = 3$.

Comment: Posted also on [mathoverflow.se]: [An olympiad-like inequality](https://mathoverflow.net/q/344504).

Comment: why is there a bounty on this? did martin R disprove it or not?

Comment: @mathworker21: Constraint is $n\ge3$ which was edited after Martin's comment.

Comment: @AngelaRichardson wrong counter-example and the RHS is $1.1$

Comment: @Hanno https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344504/an-olympiad-like-inequality is still there, with a bounty.

Comment: Thanks @GerryMyerson for spotting that. The MO post has undergone deletion, and resurrection some hours ago, and most importantly, received an answer.

Comment: I would say the "Second edit" additional codition is not required.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the inequality is not true for $n=3$ and
$$f(x) = \mathrm{e}^{ax^2 + bx + c}$$
where
\begin{align}
a &= -\frac{1}{2}\ln 10 + \frac{1}{2}\ln 800 - \ln \frac{3}{20} \approx 4.088133303, \\
b &= \frac{5}{2}\ln 10 - \frac{3}{2}\ln 800 + 4 \ln \frac{3}{20} \approx -11.85893480, \\
c &= -3\ln 10 + \ln 800 - 3\ln \frac{3}{20} \approx 5.468216404.
\end{align}

**Explanation**:

First, we have $f''(x) = \mathrm{e}^{ax^2 + bx + c}(4a^2x^2 + 4abx + b^2 + 2a)$.
It is easy to prove that $f''(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$.
Thus, $f(x)$ is a convex function on $(0, \infty)$. Also $f(x) > 0$ is obvious.

Second, we have $f(1) = \frac{1}{10}, \ f(2) = \frac{3}{20}, \ f(3) = 800$.
For convenience, denote $A = f(1), \ B = f(2), \ C = f(3)$.
By using Maple software, it is easy to check that
\begin{align}
(A+B+C) \ln (A + C - (ABC)^{1/3}) - \Big(A\ln A + B\ln B + C\ln C\Big)
\approx -0.007135.
\end{align}
This disproves the inequality.

Comment: Will the op move the goal post by excluding $n=3$ again?

Comment: Or add some constraints on $f(1), f(2), \cdots, f(n)$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool:  And indeed – the question has changed again :)

Comment: I believe this is likely to be a rounding error.

Comment: @Konstantin   First, Maple software provide high precision results. Second, if we fix $A, B$ and let $C\to \infty$, Maple software gives $\lim_{C\to \infty} (A+B+C)\ln (A+C - (ABC)^{1/3}) - (A\ln A + B\ln B + C\ln C) = -\infty$. With this in mind, we can actually disprove the inequality analytically.

Comment: @River Li Ok, it seems true that when $\frac{\max_i f_i}{\sum_i f_i} $ is close to 1 the inequality breaks and additional restrictions on the shape of $f$ are needed. Still the inequality looks very interesting.

Comment: @Konstantin  Yes. I do not know what if $\ln f(x)$ is concave. By the way, it is not hard to prove that the inequality is true if $f(x) = \alpha x$ for $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: @RiverLi OP asked about the case $f(x) = x$ here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433032/nice-inequality-22334455-cdots-nn-leq-bign1-n-frac1n-big/3433509#3433509. Can you add your solution?

Comment: @Calvin Lin   Let me take a look at that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Normalize both sides by $\sum_i f(i)$ and take a look at [case](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/veusynz7) $n=3$:

[image: Geometry of the case n=3]

Red axis corresponds to $\frac{f_2}{\sum_i f_i}$, green axis to $\frac{f_1}{\sum_i f_i}$, point $N = (\frac{1}{n},...,\frac{1}{n})$ corresponds to $f_1=f_2=...=f_n$, all points to the left of $N$ - to the convex sequences $\{f_i\}$, the curved surface corresponds to the normalized left hand side, hyperplane - to the normalized right hand side.

Rigorous proof will involve a study of the geometry of the surface given by the image of the set $\{w \in \mathbb{R}^n : \sum_i w_i = 1\}$ ([simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex)) under the map $w \to \prod_i w_i^{w_i} + \prod_i w_i^\frac{1}{n}$.

**Detailed argument:** *(to be finished)*

1. Slight change of notation:

\begin{equation}
    f_i := f(i) \quad w_i := \frac{f_i}{\sum_i f_i}.
\end{equation}

Our inequality becomes

\begin{equation}
\prod_i f_i ^{w_i} + \prod_i f_i^\frac{1}{n} \leq f_1 + f_n.
\end{equation}

2. Divide both sides of inequality by $\sum_i f_i$:

\begin{equation}
 \prod_i w_i^{w_i} + \prod_i w_i^\frac{1}{n} \leq w_1 + w_n.
\end{equation}

One can recognize entropy probability ($\exp(-H(w))$ where $H(w)$ is the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) of distribution $w$) and [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) in the functions on the left side.

\begin{equation}
    E(w) := \prod_i w_i^{w_i} \quad  G(w) := \prod_i w_i^\frac{1}{n}.
\end{equation}

3. Left hand side has a critical point $\bar w = (\frac{1}{n},...,\frac{1}{n})$.
4. Study of Hessian evaluated at this $\bar w$.
5. Study the behavior of $L(\lambda; w^*) = E(\lambda \bar w + (1-\lambda) w^*)+G(\lambda \bar w + (1-\lambda) w^*)$ depending on $w^*$.
6. ...some more math gymnastics...
7. Q.E.D.!

Comment: Reminds me of http://www.sciencecartoonsplus.com/pages/gallery.php ...

Comment: Haha, more or less. What do you have to say about the reasoning itself?

Comment: Too vague for my taste!