# Prove that an inequality holds for $\alpha \ge 2$

Tags: limits, inequality, power-series, exponentiation

It's related to my own question [Refinement inequality of : $\sqrt{x}+x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}\geq x+1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3691006/refinement-inequality-of-sqrtxx-fracxx1-geq-x1)

> > Let $x\geq 5$ be a real number then we have :
> > $$\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}\Bigg(\frac{x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}}{x^{\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}}}+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}}\Bigg)\geq x+1$$

Now the problem is:

Let :$$\frac{x^{\alpha}+1}{x+1}\Bigg(\frac{x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}}{x^{\frac{x^{\alpha}}{x^{\alpha}+1}}}+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}}\Bigg)\geq x+1$$

Prove that $\alpha=2$ is the best constant, i.e. the above holds for $\alpha=2$ and fails for $\alpha<2$.

I have tried to prove $0<\epsilon<2$:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^{2-\epsilon}+1}{x+1}\Bigg(\frac{x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}}{x^{\frac{x^{2-\epsilon}}{x^{2-\epsilon}+1}}}+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}}\Bigg) -(x+1)=-\infty$$

Using the series provided in my previous answer without success.

Comment: Erm - define "best"?

Comment: @K.defaoite best in the sense that if we take a value $<2$ the inequality is not valid .It start from $2$ .Is it clear ? Thanks.