# Tight upper bound for the binary entropy function

Tags: calculus, inequality, maxima-minima, entropy

The binary entropy function is defined as $H_2(x) = -x\log_2(x) - (1-x)\log_2(1-x)$. I am aware of the upper bound $2\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ provided in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432043/an-upper-bound-of-binary-entropy) already.

One of the answers implies that $H_2(x) \leq (4x(1-x))^{\frac{3}{4}} + 0.008$. From Wolfram Alpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Power%5B%5C%2840%294x%5C%2840%291-x%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2CDivide%5B3%2C4%5D%5D%2B0.007+-+%5C%2840%29-x+log%5C%2840%292%5C%2844%29x%5C%2841%29+-+%5C%2840%291-x%5C%2841%29log%5C%2840%292%5C%2844%291-x%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29+minimum+in+%5C%2891%290%5C%2844%291%5C%2893%29), it seems obvious that in fact $H_2(x) \leq (4x(1-x))^{\frac{3}{4}} + 0.007$. Is there a nice way to show this?

Comment: Apparently you are referring to the claim at the end of this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1432228/42969. – You could ask Jack for a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a more systematic treatment of this question which I can refer to here. So this "replaces" in a way the precise bound in the question, I hope this is fine with OP.

One can ask the following question: suppose we want to establish an upper bound
$$H_2(x) \leq c \cdot (x(1-x))^{q} \quad ,$$
with some constant $c$, what is the largest $q^*$ where this is possible?

You have already noticed that $q= 0.5$ is possible. You tried to improve that and found that  $q= 0.75$ is "almost" possible. To make it strict,  you (and Jack D'Aurizio) needed an extra additive constant.

The following results are taken from the paper  "Bounds for entropy and divergence for distributions over a two-element set" by Topsøe, Flemming. In:  JIPAM. Journal of Inequalities in Pure & Applied Mathematics. 2 (2): Paper No. 25 (2001). [Link to pdf.](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/044_00_JIPAM/044_00.pdf) Note when you read the paper that Topsøe uses natural logarithms so a little transformation is necessary.

From Topsøe's paper, the answer to the above question is $q^* = 1 / \ln(4) \simeq 0.721$ (which is close to your $0.75$). In this case, $c^* =  4^{q^*} = e \simeq 2.718 $, which can be compared to the constant in your proposition, $c = 4^{3/4} \simeq 2.82$, again very close.

Since $c^* =  4^{q^*}$ this is also a very good reason  to include a factor $4$ into the RHS of the proposition, which you and Topsøe have done. Another reason is establishing the equality  at $x^* = 0.5$, where for all $q$ holds:
$1 = H_2(x^*) =  (4 \, x^*(1-x^*))^{q} $.

Again, I modified your question for the reason of improving the somewhat arbitrary constant + exponent proposition and to make the treatment more concise, hope that is fine with you.